# How to extract username and public key from a website using xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

For my thesis work I am gathering data from bitcointalk.org about the users and their bitcoin public keys which they give at the end of each post they write(for donations and tips).

```
<td valign="top" width="16%" rowspan="2" style="overflow: hidden;" class="poster_info">
                        <b><a href="https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=2786" title="View the profile of Pieter Wuille">Pieter Wuille</a></b>
```

I am trying to extract the username value from the above syntax using xpath and also the value of public key for the user from the signature field from the below syntax

```
<div class="signature sig2786">aka sipa, core dev team<br /><br />Tips and donations: 1KwDYMJMS4xq3ZEWYfdBRwYG2fHwhZsipa</div>
```

My code to extract the items is given below

```
site.xpath('.//td[@class="poster_info"]/b/a/text()').extract()
site.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "signature")]/text()').re(r'(1[1-9A-HJ-  NP-Za-km-z]{26,33})')
```

The code works fine but what it does is that it extracts all the usernames and all the bitcoin keys that (the user gave at the end of the post for donation) on a page and there is no way to associate the key to a user since they are extracted separately what I want to do is extract the information in a pair so that I could omit the users who have not specified their public keys(for donation) in their post. Can anyone help me? I am kind of stuck

Comment: Could you refine your issue? I don't see a problem raised in your issue. "some users have no signature field" <- that's not an issue we can help you with.

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully its clear now

Comment: So on every page there's only one user and one or less keys? Could you maybe provide an url? I think I understand your issue but I don't really understand the structure of the website you're crawling here.

Comment: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1474398.0, actually there can be more then one user but not every one of them has/shares a public key asking for donations, so I only need to scrape the data for the users who share their public keys

Answer (score 0):

So from what you've described in the comments you want to do is find users in the forum thread got to each of their profiles and if they have a bitcoin address in their profiles scrape the address and their usersname, right? This is the spider that pretty much does that:

```
 class BitcointalkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bitcointalk"
    allowed_domains = ["bitcointalk.org"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1474398.0/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        # find profile urls
        profiles = response.xpath("//a[contains(@title,'View the profile')]/@href").extract()
        profiles = list(set(profiles))  # only unique values
        # scrape every one of them individually
        for pro in profiles:
            yield scrapy.Request(pro, self.parse_profile)

    def parse_profile(self, response):
        bitcoin = response.xpath("//td[contains(.//text(),'Bitcoin address')]"
                                 "/following-sibling::td/text()").extract_first()
        if not bitcoin:  # no bitcoin, drop user
            return
        item = dict()
        item['bitcoin_address'] = bitcoin
        item['username'] = response.xpath("//td[contains(.//text(),'Name')]"
                                          "/following-sibling::td/text()").extract_first()
        return item
```

Comment: no I don't want to go to respective profile pages, I want to scrape it from the webpage itself, because it goes through every page in the bitcointalk and wherever it encounters a user who has mentioned its public key, it just scrapes the data for that user and proceeds further

Comment: @NikhilJain you mean mentioned bitcoin coin in the post text body?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've the idea about getting a common ancestor so that you can match each author to its public key, but I think you're missing the correct selectors, for example try this:

```
posts = response.css('.windowbg, .windowbg2')
for post in posts:
    author = post.css('.poster_info>b>a::text').extract_first()
    bitcoinkey = post.css('.signature').re_first(r'(1[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{26,33})')
    if author and bitcoinkey:
        print author, bitcoinkey
```